# Calculating the determinant of a matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ such that $a_{ij}=ij$ if $i \neq j$ and $a_{ij}=1+ij$ if $i=j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, determinant, problem-solving

**Here is my attempt :**

If order of $A$ is $2$, then $$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 2  \\
        2 & 5  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
 \Rightarrow \det A=6.$$
Also the eigenvalues in this case are $1,6$.

If order $A$ is $3$, then $$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 2 & 3 \\
        2 & 5 & 6 \\
        3 & 6 & 10 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\Rightarrow \det A=15$$
Also the eigenvalues in these case are $1,1,15.$

If order of $A$ is $4$, then $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        2 & 5 & 6 & 8\\
        3 & 6 & 10 & 12\\
        4 & 8 & 12 & 17\\
\end{pmatrix}
\Rightarrow \det A=-21.$$
I found that $1$ is an eigenvalue here by directly putting $\lambda=1$ in the characteristic determinant. But $-21$ is not the eigenvalue.

I couldn't use information about eigenvalues so I looked at the pattern of determinants :

$6,15,-21,...?$ Observed that they are $3\times 2,3 \times 5,-3 \times 7$. From this pattern it might be possible that next term is $-3 \times 11$ since $2,5,7$ are primes and next is $11$. Also the negative sign can be in the pattern $+,+,-,-,+,+,-,-,+,+...$ As it seems to me I will have to calculate order $5$ too to get some more concrete idea with respect to this way. But isn't there some elegant method?

I see that every such order $n$ matrix is "engraved to upper-left inside" order $n+1$ such matrix and every $A$ is symmetric. Thanks.

**PS :** I wrongly calculated $\det A_{4 \times 4}=-21$. It should be $31$.

Comment: Note that $A=I+vv^T$, where $v^T=(1,2,\ldots,n)$, is a rank-1 update to the identity matrix.

Comment: @user1551 Interesting! Thanks a lot. $\det (I +vv^T)=1+v^T v$ is much helpful. +1

Comment: Note the [exact duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577937/calculating-detai-for-matrix-a-defined-by-products) which was linked within the "abstract" duplicate Question referenced above (calculating the determinant for a matrix defined by products).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks. Got it! +1